# Facebook wall post publishing access

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

I've written a Facebook app that includes taking permissions to post on the user's timeline. I'm using the extended token which allows me to have access to the token for up to two months, this also allows me to publish without being logged into to Facebook.

My question is, does this break any Facebook rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't (from my own experience), however you might want to bold that you have the ability to post on their wall when asking for the users permission.

Worth reading the docs also.

> You can publish to a person's timeline by issuing HTTP POST requests to the appropriate connection URLs, using an access token.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/